# Ableton Live/M-Audio Fast Track conflict with USB keyboard

Tags: ableton-live, midi-interface

I am using Ableton Live 6 Lite with M-Audio Fast Track connected through USB port. I am having the following issue which I do not know how to resolve: I cannot simultaneously use sound recording with the above mentioned setup and a USB connected keyboard (just a regular USB keyboard which I use with my Toshiba Laptop PC). Either keyboard is not working or no sound reaches Ableton Live software. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a USB hub which does not have its own power source.  You are drawing too much current so only one device can be powered at a time.  Use USB ports directly on your computer or get a USB hub with its own power adapter.

Comment: Brad, my M-Audio device is powered up, so it should not draw any power from the USB, it is also plugged straight into a USB port, so I am not sure what you mean by USB hub. What do you mean by using USB ports directly? Could you elaborate, please? Thank you!